# What's the most plain way to define a parametrized macro within an outer macro definition

Tags: macros, tex-core, plain-tex

I often want to pass some arguments into a macro definition that defines an inner macro with parameters. For example

```
\def\outmac #1,#2.{%
    \def\argone{#1}
    \def\argtwo{#2}
    \def\inmac #1,#2.{Parameters are 1:#1 and 2:#2,
        while outer parameters are 1:\argone, 2:\argtwo.}
}
```

So I can say `\outmac a,b.\inmac c,d.` to get

```
Parameters are 1:c and 2:d, while outer parameters are 1:a, 2:b.
```

. In other words: A call to `\outmac` should defines the way `\inmac` behaves.

Regards

Ingo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\def\outmac #1,#2.{%
    \def\inmac ##1,##2.{Parameters are 1:##1 and 2:##2,
        while outer parameters are 1:#1, 2:#2.}%
}
```